# Jquery doesn't work with angularjs dynamically created data

Tags: jquery, angularjs, laravel

I want to add 'Edit products' function to my e-shop administrator panel. I'am using laravel as backend and angular as front. But for file-upload function i using Jquery.
This button onclick load all products from server and pass them in products array:

```
<button ng-click="controlPanel.showChangeItems()" class="btn btn-default">
        Change
</button>
```

And add it to page

```
<div ng-class="{ 'hide' : controlPanel.state != 'changeItem'}">
        <div class="products" ng-repeat="product in products">
        ...
        {{Form::open(['url'=>'postUpload', 'files'=>true, 'class'=>'uploadImageForm'])}}
                    {{Form::file('photo')}}
                    <div class="wait wait-photo"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Please, wait...</div>
                    {{Form::submit('Upload', ['class'=>'btn btn-default'])}}
                    <span class="uploadSuccess" style="color:green"></span>
        {{Form::close()}}
</div>
```

This form works good when i add it manually. But doesn't work when dynamically.
Here is my jquery code:

```
$('.uploadImageForm').on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.wait-photo').show();
    $('.upload-photo').hide();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: new FormData(this),
      type: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(output) {
        $('.photo').val(output);
        $('.uploadSuccess').text('Success!');
        $('.wait-photo').hide();
        $('.upload-photo').show();
      },
      error: function(output) {
        alert('Error! Try again later');
      }
    });
```

With server side all is ok, because when i place form manually all works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing angular DOM using jQuery would be bad thing.

Write the code in directive to take better control over a `DOM`

**HTML**

```
<form name="something" form-directive>
  Inner Content
</form>
```

**CODE**

```
app.directive('formDirective', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                angular.element('.wait-photo').show();
                angular.element('.upload-photo').hide();
                $http.post(element.attr('action'), new FormData(this), {
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false
                }).then(function(output) {
                    angular.element('.photo').val(output);
                    angular.element('.uploadSuccess').text('Success!');
                    angular.element('.wait-photo').hide();
                    angular.element('.upload-photo').show();
                }, function(output) {
                    alert('Error! Try again later');
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this could help. Thanks.